# Prove the matrix-vector-product is linear

Tags: matrices, vectors

> Prove the following for Matrices $A, B \in K^{m×n}$, vectors $u, v \in K^n$ and $λ, γ \in K$:
> $$(λA + γB)v = λ(Av) + γ(Bv)\quad \textrm{ and } \quad A(λu + γv) = λ(Au) + γ(Av).$$

I know that:
(BUT i'm not allowed to use it):
$T(λu+γv)=λT(u)+ γT(v)$ $\qquad$ (definition of linear transformation) 
For any scalar $\lambda$ and vector u: $A(\lambda u)=\lambda Au$ 
For any two vectors $u$ and $v$: $A(u + v)=Au +Av$.

My problem is that I don't know how to do this WITHOUT using the definition of linear transformation.

Comment: That's pretty much it, unless your instructor actually wanted you to break it down into the definitions of matrix multiplication element wise.

Comment: @Alan after messaging with my tutor he said, that while this would be a solid proof, im not allowed to use the definition of linear transformation, so i think ill have to break it down into the elements.. any hints / tips?

Comment: Use summation notation and show that the dot product of two vectors is linear,  the rest pops out immediately as matrix multiplication is just a sum of dot products